# Correct place to report outdated homebrew formula

Tags: github, homebrew, issue-tracking, cgdb

Where should the github issue be placed for an outdated homebrew formuae; homebrew's github, or somewhere on the project maintainers' side?

For a formula I've been trying out, [cgdb](https://github.com/cgdb/cgdb), it seems that in their 0.6.8 release, they fixed a bug that's been affecting my computer. This version has been released as of November 13th of 2014. However, [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/cgdb.rb) (from which I installed `cgdb`) has the 0.6.7 release.

So where should the issue be placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a Homebrew maintainer, I'd be delighted if you could open a pull request against Homebrew to update the package. Nobody has a defined responsibility to keep packages updated, though some projects choose to submit updates to us directly; we depend on user contributions to keep Homebrew current. Here is a guide; I'm happy to walk you through the process if you have any questions. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/How-To-Open-a-Homebrew-Pull-Request-(and-get-it-merged).md

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Since then, I've created a pull request for the issue here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/35843

Comment: Here's the correct repo nowadays: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core

Answer (score 0):

If it is a bug/issue specific to Homebrew, you should post it to their Github repo.

If it is related to a specific formula, you should post it to the Github repo of that formula.

Comment: Right, but the question is, who's in charge of keeping the Homebrew commit up to date? If I recall correctly, it's the package creator's responsibility to do so - so the maintainers of `cgdb`.